# numeric-only textbox as a control in Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dotnetnuke

I would like to make one numeric-only textbox. I'd like to then add that same to the control toolbox within Visual Studio 2008

I've already built the function to allow only numeric.

How can I make it available in the toolbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can create numeric `TextBox`:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i knew this..
 hiw can i make it as a control.

Comment: ont textbox that allows only numeric the same control i can use it for any of my projects..

Comment: make this class library, and then right click to project, add new item, add new icon file for your class, rename it NumericTB. And go to toolbox, right click, choose items, and choose your numeric textbox dll. and you call it like [System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("KeyPress"), DefaultProperty("Text"), System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmap(@"../../NumericTB.ico")]

Comment: Ouch. You're missing a whole lot of things. Decimal point, tousands separator, minus sign are only three of them. Copy/paste will still allow you to enter non-numeric characters. You can enter any decimal digit you like (regardless of script) – I doubt anything will reliably parse that. There's quite a lot of issues here and designing sucha  control properly takes more than three lines of code.

Comment: As well, the poster indicated dotnetnuke, which is web.  This wouldn't work in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on key press

```
  function NumberOnly(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this in the textchanged event of the textbox.

here is a demo

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string actualdata = string.Empty;
        char[] entereddata = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char aChar in entereddata.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(aChar))
            {
                actualdata = actualdata + aChar;
                // MessageBox.Show(aChar.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(aChar + " is not numeric");
                actualdata.Replace(aChar, ' ');
                actualdata.Trim();
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = actualdata;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Download this:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx

EDIT:

Okay. I am getting downvoted for some three-year old advice. Currently, I would recommend looking into the contents of jQuery UI.

Comment: OP wants winforms, not javascript - I guess that's why you were downvoted.