# New Windows Forms Item

Tags: c#

First of all, I have no idea what these are called so I had no way of searching to see if this question existed.

Essentially, I'm looking to create a new item that gets added to the Toolbox, like a Textbox. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170751) but it was posted 5 years ago and had trouble understanding how it worked.

I tried creating a Class Library, importing `System.Windows.Forms` so I could inherit `Textbox` but it kept saying that `Forms` is not a namespace or type in `System.Windows`.

What do I do? Also, what are these called so I can search in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in your project like this:

Step 1 : Go to **MenuBar -> Project -> Add Reference**.

[image: Step 1]

Step 2: On the left, navigate to **Assemblies -> Framework**. On the right scroll down and make sure **System.Windows.Forms** is checked. Click OK.

[image]

Similarly, for other errors like that, make sure that there is a reference to the assembly the error points to and if not add it using the steps above.

The error that you get is called a **'Missing Assembly Reference Error'**.

Comment: I forgot to select the checkbox... Now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: So you even knew that you needed an assembly reference? That's great. Small things **can** make a difference. I too thought that it was weird because of your high reputation!

Comment: I'm new to Visual Studio and C# as a whole. When I saw "Add Reference" I found what I wanted, clicked it, and hit okay. "Add" just doesn't seem like the correct word, but, whatever.